# A linear mapping for truncated multivariate normal distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $n$-vector $\mathbf{x}$ is a truncated multivariate normal distribution where $\mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{0}$.

Suppose $\mathbf{W} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A}\\ \mathbf{I}_n \end{bmatrix}$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, where $m > n$ and $rank(\mathbf{W}) = n$ and $\mathbf{A}$ is a matrix with 1s and 0s. What is the distribution of $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{Wx}$?

If $\mathbf{x}$ is multivariate normal then $\mathbf{y}$ has a singular multivariate normal distribution.

I wonder whether we can have a truncated singular multivariate normal distribution when $\mathbf{x}$ is a truncated multivariate normal distribution.